# Объединение одинаковых элементов в объекте

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

```
  'foo.bar18=7c447b740acd8213a90808a7949b22b6&boo.foo=10&foo.id=3'
```

, которую пропустил сквозь `reduce` и получил:

```
  { foo: { bar18: { '7c447b740acd8213a90808a7949b22b6': [Object] } } }
```

, а потом сквозь JSON.stringify и получил:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar18": {
      "7c447b740acd8213a90808a7949b22b6": {
        "boo": {
          "foo": {
            "10": {
              "foo": {
                "id": "3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как я могу убрать повторяющиеся элементы(foo, boo и т.д)?

Есть такая вещь, как `Object.assign`, но я верно что-то не так делаю, ибо не происходит ничего.

*И офф-топ*: почему так много вложений получается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будем считать, что исходная строка - это query_string, то есть состоит из ряда пар имя и значение, которые разделены знаком равенства, а сами пары разделяются символом амперсант или точка с запятой.

```js
console.log(

    't=q&foo.bar18=7c447b740acd&boo.foo=10&foo.id=3'

        // разделяет исходную строку на пары имя и значение
        // (сплитим по разделителю пар, получаем массив строк вида ["a.z=b", "c=d"])
        .split(/[&;]/)

        // каждый элемент массива пар разделяем по "=",
        // т.о. каждый элемент массива превращаем в массив вида [имя, значение]
        // в этой точке данные имеют вид [["a.z", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
        .map(x => x.split('='))

        // мы помним, что у нас массив массивов,
        // в 0вом элементе массива у нас имя (параметра),
        // имя может представлять собой последовательность ключей
        // разделённых символом точка. привычно делаем из этой строки массив.
        // в этой точке данные имеют вид [[["a", "z"], "b"], [["c"], "d"]]
        .map(x => (x[0] = x[0].split('.')) && x)

        //
        .reduce((map, x) => {
            // в x[0] у нас хранится последовательность ключей сверху вниз
            // наша задача пройти по ней и присвоить ключу на последнем уровне значение из x[1]

            // откусываем имя ключа последнего уровня
            let lastKey = x[0].pop();

            // внутри аккумулятора map проходимся по последовательности ключей
            // и возвращаем значение по ключу
            // (либо инициализируем его в объект и возвращаем)
            // в итоге мы получим "предпоследний" уровень - в него и пишем данные
            x[0].reduce((xmap, k) => (xmap[k] || (xmap[k] = {})), map)[lastKey] = x[1];
            return map;
        }, {})
    
);
```

Должен сказать, что этот же код можно сделать эффективнее перенеся в reduce обработку подстрок (логику двух map-ов, которые следуют после первого split), но цель этих map-ов в том чтобы достичь большей наглядности, более явно показать этапы обработки строки.

Это, скорее, демонстрационный вариант решения и для того чтобы использовать его на проекте нужно разобраться с несколькими недостатками (впрочем, их легко исправить):

- строка вида `foo.bar=1&foo.bar=2` должна в результате быть такой `{foo: {bar: [1,2]}}`, но будет такой `{foo: {bar: 2}}`. это исправляется проверкой наличия **lastKey** на "предпоследнем уровне"
- обработка строки вида `foo=1&foo.bar=2` породит исключение. нужно следить за типом данных в `xmap[k]`
- результатом обработки строки вида `foo.0.z=1&foo.1.bar=2` должен быть массив. наверное :)

Comment: В итоге должно получиться вот как-то вот так: 
{"foo": {"bar18": "7c447b740acd8213a90808a7949b22b6","id":"3"},"boo": {"foo":10}}

Comment: это и получается :) нажми на "Выполнить код"

Comment: Господи! Никогда не совмещайте несколько разноплановых деятельностей головой в короткий промежуток времени (js и университет), а то будете позориться из-за невнимательности.

Прошу у Вас прощения и приношу огромную благодарность!

Comment: Можно не скромную просьбу? Вы не могли бы оставить комментарии внутри кода? Я его до конца не понимаю :(

Comment: прокомментировал

Comment: большое вам спасибо за труды) Вы делаете студентов менее безграмотными)