# Строки, split . амперсанд

Tags: javascript

Имеется строка:

```
str='foo.bar18=7c447b740acd82137949b22b6&boo.foo=10&foo.id=3';
```

Пытаюсь через конструкцию

```
str.toString().split(/\.|=&/);
```

,разделить её.

На выходе получаю

```
 [ 'foo',
 'bar18=7c447b740acd82137949b22b6&boo',
'foo=10&foo',
'id=3' ]
```

Как можно заметить, амперсанд успешно продолжает подрывную деятельность. Нид ,очень сильно, хелп

Comment: чем тебе не подошел мой ответ на твой предыдущий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831367/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)? в ответе я попытался показать каждый этап обработки этой строки до получения объекта

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Объединение одинаковых элементов в объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831367/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @norbornen ваш ответ не решил задачи прошлого вопроса - не убрал повторяющиеся элементы. Я пошёл иным путём, но за ваш вариант - спасибо

Comment: поясни что ты подразумеваешь под повторяющимися элементами

Comment: @norbornen я вполне могу ошибиться в терминологии, называя вещи внутри объекта элементами, но я говорил foo, boo и т.д которые повторяются

Comment: на мой взгляд boo не повторяется, а foo - это разные foo. напиши в самом вопросе какую структуру ты хочешь получить в результате и почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что экранировать его надо.

```js
const str='foo.bar18=7c447b740acd82137949b22b6&boo.foo=10&foo.id=3';
console.log(str.split(/\.|\=|\&/));
```

Comment: @HegoJune Вы там еще забыли `|`, и искалось строго `=&` а не равно или амперсанд